# Step List With Elixir

Tags: elixir

Can someone please provide a suggestion on how to iterate a list BUT with a batch of x at a time?

#### For example:

If the functionality existed:

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"].step(5)|> IO.puts
```

Would produce in two iterations:

> > 12345
> >
> > 678910

I believe Stream.iterate/2 is the solution but my attempts to do so given an **array** are not proving profitable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Enum.chunk_every/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/2) (or [Stream.chunk_every/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#chunk_every/2)) will break a list down into sublists of x elements:

```
iex> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] |> Enum.chunk_every(5)                   
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

You can then act on each list, for example:

```
iex> ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
     |> Enum.chunk_every(5)
     |> Enum.each(fn x -> IO.puts x end)
12345
678910
```

Comment: This doesn't give a perfect solution. If the list-size is not a multiple of chunk-size, it will leave the remainder number of elements out. For example, if the array is ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"], the result will now include 11 & 12.

Comment: @KshitijMittal In that case you can use http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Enum.html#chunk/4 `list |> Enum.chunk(5, 5, [])`

Comment: @Gazler thanks. the docs, for me at least, are very difficult to understand. Very minimal on examples and very short on wording.

Answer (score 1):

Both Enum.chunk/2 and Enum.chunk/2 are deprecated.

Use [Enum.chunk_every/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/Enum.html#chunk_every/2) and [Stream.chunk_every/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/Stream.html#chunk_every/2) instead

Comment: I've updated the other answer too.